# When I destroy a Google Cloud Storage Bucket, how is the data deleted?

Tags: security, google-cloud-storage

Is the data in the bucket securely deleted (ex DoD 5220.22-M) or do I need to do that myself before destroying the bucket?

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a bucket, all of its contents are deleted as well. In the Cloud Console, if you select a bucket and click the Delete button, a prompt appears and tells you that the bucket's content will be deleted permanently.

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-buckets) can show you the different options for deleting a bucket. You can do it through the Cloud Console, the `gsutil` command, using the client libraries on a programming language or through REST APIs.